# Uri path param in jetty 9 websocket

Tags: jetty, jetty-9, java-websocket

I have created websocket using spark 2.5 runs on jetty 9 server

on client side URI looks like in  websocket client : ws://localhost:8004/myservice/clientid

on Server Websocket , @websocketconnect i want to build logic using 'clientid'

How to capture the path param in jetty 9 websocket?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to answering this, but I came across this as well. It looks like `session.getUpgradeRequest().getRequestURI()` provides the full path. You can split it up and get anything that comes after `myservice/...` to get your `clientid` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Map with all your parameter and corresponding value.
`session.getUpgradeRequest().getParameterMap()`